# Centering text over an IMAGE BUTTON, while driving the text hover effect from hovering over the image- not the text

Tags: javascript, css

I have a set of buttons in which I need the text to - eventually - change based on country.
This means that I have to use a text element to be part of the button. Since the button has hover effect, I need the text to be contained inside the image div.
By using the "", I get the text to be position correctly, but the problems are:

A: the text responds to the pointer way outside the image boundary (which actually causing the click to activate a different button.
B: if the pointer is placed directly over the text, only the text get highlighted (through the hover effect), but not the button.
I am looking for a solution (either via CSS or JavaScript) that will make the button perform correctly e.g. the button will respond pointer hover over to the image only, but will still highlight the text (as if the text was part of the - and not separate as it actually is).
Note that since the text and image elements are screen-size adaptive, all distances and sizes must be percentage based)

See Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HypeTsu/E3fr7/2/): 
Note what happens when you hover just on top of the image. Also note what happens when you touch the edges of the image VS the center...

```
<div id="main_positioning_container">

     <div id="my_account_dashboard_container">

            <div id="contact_information_icon"
                style="color:#292726"
                onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#f48325'"
                onMouseOut="this,style.color = '#292726'" > 
                    <img src="../icons/icon_ContactInforrmation_inactive.png"
                    img         onMouseOver="this.src='../icons/icon_ContactInforrmation_hover.png'"
                    onMouseOut="this.src='../icons/icon_ContactInforrmation_inactive.png'"
                    alt="icon_ContactInforrmation_inactive" 
                    width="100%" 
                    hight="auto"
                    style="margin-bottom: -20%;">
                       <p align="center">Contact Information</p> 
            </div>

      </div>

</div>



#main_positioning_container {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
    left: 0px;
}

#my_account_dashboard_container {
    visibility:visible;
}

#contact_information_icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #292726;
    font: Kalinga;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 13.75%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with all the necessary code?

Comment: TX for the tip. I've added a Fiddle and cleaned up the post and code to focus on the problem.

Comment: I don't see the image or the button in the fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure why - it works on my end. Please try to re size your browser and see if the image comes into view. I have doubled and tripled check this fiddle before posting...

Comment: It's probable because the image file is missing on my end...

Comment: Jegesh, please try this Fiddle with Chrome. I have checked with my friends to make sure the Fiddle works for them - and it does

Comment: I'm using chrome. All I see is the words 'contactt information'

Comment: Please try the direct - full screen link ( http://jsfiddle.net/HypeTsu/E3fr7/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: I now see a lightly colored rectangle that contains the text. Is this the button?  I don't see any other image, either.

Comment: Yes. The image is a long rectangle - text shows up in the middle.

Comment: What about the button?

Comment: I don't know why you don't see it. It is hosted by PostImage. It works for me and my associates...

Comment: Ah, there's the answer! My ISP filters out PostImage as well as many other sites that could supply potentially obscene or otherwise unseemly content (it's _kosher_).

Comment: That's great news. Any thoughts on how to correct my text problem?

Comment: It's sort of hard for me to understand the problem without being able to experience it.  Maybe you can move the file I don't see to a different site, like picasa or flickr